# Какой элемент рвет верстку?

Tags: вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка, responsive

Имеется сайт с респонсивной версткой. В демо шаблона все идеально, проверял как на реальных устройствах, так и через Device Toolbar в Google Chrome.
Перерыл все элементы на предмет размеров и отступов, не могу найти какой элемент ломает верстку, прошу помощи.

[сайт](https://makefishing.ru/)

P.S. Знаю что такие вопросы не принесут пользу сообществу и от них нет никакого толка при хранении, поэтому прошу не минусовать, сам удалю вопрос после решения.

[image: Скрин проблемы]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ширина `.log-panel` составляет 111px. Не смотря на то, что там находятся 2 элемента по 54px.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему так произошло и откуда лишние пиксели? Проблема в лишнем пробеле:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Остальные кнопки имеют ширину в 54px.

При этом, размер родителя составляет 272px.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Отсюда 111 + 54х3 = 273px. Поэтому последний элемент, не поместившись в отведенные рамки переносится на новую строку.

Comment: Огромное человеческое спасибо! Проблема поиска оказалась в инструменте исследования :). GС не показывает в инспекторе текстовые узлы, да я видел что ширина этого элемента 111px но почему она такая если 2 вложенных в нее элемента по 54px я не понимал, попросту пробел не был виден.

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь Я использую Firefox Developer Edition, там очень много полезных штук для разработки. Не говорю, что Chrome чем-то хуже, дело привычки. Как видите, в данному случае такая мелочь стала весьма полезной.

Answer (score 0):

У ссылок есть фиксированная ширина в 54px. При ее уменьшении на 1px все входит (видно на скрине) => стоит с ней поиграться.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Размер в 54px по ширине соответствует тому же размеру в демо, в том то и дело, что вопрос заключается, почему в демо при той же ширине все ок, а тут нет... Смена размеров на 1px это костыль. Вопрос задавался, с целью выяснить причину, а не как исправить костылем.

Comment: Если посмотреть на элемент #quick-nav то видно что его ширина 272px. 272/5 = 54,4 все должно влазить.

Comment: `#quick-nav` 272px, а `#logo-handler` 54px.
272 + 54 = 326px при максимальном размере экрана 320px
Не сходится. А вот почему...

Comment: Потому что #quick-nav смещен влево и налазит на логотип. В демо это видно также как и тут. Позиция #quick-nav 48 слева.